# "Module "QtQuick" version 2.7 is not installed" Error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, qt

I am attempting to develop a GUI for some Python code that I have already written for an insulin pump. I've been using QT Quick as it seems the easiest for a beginner (it doesn't need to be super fancy, it just needs to work). Although the qml script runs fine when I try to run it on my computer, when I attempt to run it on my Raspberry Pi, it returns the error that QtQuick is not installed. I've tried installing all of the relevant dependencies, but that does nothing to clear up the error message. The script I'm using to run it is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QUrl('MainForm.ui.qml'))
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QUrl('MainForm.ui.qml'))
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My QtQuick code is this.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Rectangle {
    property alias mouseArea: mouseArea

    width: 360
    height: 360
    property alias button2: button2

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        enabled: true
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.fill: parent


        Button {
            id: button
            x: 40
            y: 208
            width: 68
            height: 28
            text: qsTr("Basal")
            font.pixelSize: 13
            font.capitalization: Font.Capitalize
            enabled: true
            visible: true
            opacity: 0.5
            spacing: -22
        }

        Button {
            id: button1
            x: 253
            y: 208
            width: 68
            height: 28
            text: qsTr("Bolus")
        }


        Button {
            id: button2
            x: 130
            y: 145
            text: qsTr("Status")
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 20
        }

        Button {
            id: button3
            x: 145
            y: 208
            width: 71
            height: 28
            text: qsTr("Settings")
            autoExclusive: true
        }

        Image {
            id: image
            x: 12
            y: 38
            width: 336
            height: 75
            source: "../Downloads/Pump Logo.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

So, what do you think I need to do differently?

Comment: What version of pyqt5 do you have installed? If this version does not match the version of your computer you will have similar problems, the libraries of qml are versioned so I recommend you to change the version `import QtQuick 2.7` to a previous one for example `import QtQuick 2.6`, you have installed pyqt5 through apt-get verifies that you have installed the necessary module, to get all the name of the modules run: `sudo apt-cache search pyqt5` and install all the packages from that list.

Comment: I just installed all of the packages that came up through the search and tried it with both QtQuick 2.6 and 2.7. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: Try changing the version, the version depends on the Qt you have installed, version 2.7 is for Qt 5.7 forward.

Comment: I just tried Qt Quick 2.3-2.7 but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?